# FastJSON - How to use?

Tags: c#, .net, json, fastjson

I've started using FastJSON and I'm having some problems for use it. I can't find any guide or documentation in internet, only a little extract in CodeProject.

For example: I've got this class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Prueba
{
    public Prueba()
    {
        prueba1 = 5;
        prueba2 = 6;
        prueba3 = "Hola";
    }

    public int prueba1 { get; set; }
    public int prueba2 { get; set; }
    public string prueba3 { get; set; }
}
```

If I execute `fastJSON.JSON.ToJSON(new Prueba())` i am getting this string:

> {"$types":{"WebApplication3.Prueba, WebApplication3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null":"1"},"$type":"1","prueba1":5,"prueba2":6,"prueba3":"Hola"}

But I was expecting this string:

> "{"prueba1":5,"prueba2":6,"prueba3":"Hola"}"

As you can see, it is including some assembly information that I don't want in the string. I have tried playing with JSONParameters class, but I don't see any property for this situation.

So... Do you know how configure this?? Do you know any guide or documentation on internet to understand well how fastJSON works??

Thanks a lot,
Regards

Comment: what happens if you initialise Prueba and only then pass the instance to the method?

Comment: @Orangesandlemons `new Prueba()` initializes(creates) a new instance ?

Comment: @FelixD. of Prueba, yes.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons Happens exactly the same thing :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try setting   `UseSerializerExtension` to false:

Something like:

```
fastJSON.JSON.Instance.UseSerializerExtension = false;
fastJSON.JSON.ToJSON(new Prueba());
```

**EDIT**

It appears the API has changed. You now need to pass an instance of `JSONParameters`

Like this

```
fastJSON.JSON.ToJSON(new Prueba(), new JSONParameters(){UseExtensions = false});
```

Comment: is it supposed to be `fastKSON`? I wanted to edit it but its not 6 characters :)

Comment: It appears i have fat fingers :)

Comment: Hi Alex, other error I get is trying to use Instance on fastJSON.JSON. Compiler say me that "fastJSON.JSON does not contain a definition for Instance". ¿Do you know why? Thanks!!

Comment: @Neoff where does `fastJSON` come from? Can you show more of your code

Comment: @Alex I've created a new webforms application project (begining from zero) and i've installed fastJSON through Nuget Manager Window... 

On References, fastjson Library has been include by nuget.

Comment: Exactly @Alex , with JSONParameters is solved. As there's no documentation about fastJSON I don't know what means each parameter.

Thank you so much for all your help!!!